# In SPA application, when we use no-store for index.html, does it affect other html, js and css files?

Tags: single-page-application, browser-cache

In a single page application when we are adding 
`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />` metatag in header, does other it affect other html, js ,css files?? becoz no-store will not save any cache in browser, which means index.html files are always latest from server. Does other html, js, css files be cached or they wil always take latest from server ??  Becoz in SPA all other html are rendered in same file

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not hold html files apart from index.html or anything specified in assets, the rest are templates and are compiled and served from JavaScript and in production every JavaScript file has an id attached to the filename for cache busting. So it is always the latest regardless if no-store is or isn't present.